# PHP: calling a python script throws ModuleNotFoundError, calling from terminal works just fine?

Tags: python, php, modulenotfounderror

I have a script, let's call it `/home/pi/somescript.py` and when I call it with `/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/somescript.py` everything works as it should.

Now I'm trying to call from a php script with `exec('/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/somescript.py', $output, $ret_code);`. This however throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

But when I run the interactive PHP shell and paste the above `exec` in there, it also works. Am I missing something? What could be the cause of this? How do I fix this?

The relevant part of the python script:

```
import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout    # so I get the stacktrace in the $output of the php file

from iso3166 import countries    # <- error here
# ...
```

I'm running a `lighttpd` server. The PHP file lies in `/var/www/html/info.php` and I access it via a browser with `http://raspberrypi:8080/info.php`
The relevant part of the PHP file:

```
exec('/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/somescript.py', $output, $ret_code);
$data = ["out" => $output];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
// this way I get the output when in the browser
```

The stacktrace I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/somescript.py", line 6, in <module>
    from iso3166 import countries
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iso3166'
```

Comment: Please show us the related code and the full error traceback and also explain how you run the PHP file!

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out? I am having the same problem.